# What does it mean when for all $M>0$,$f$ is integrable on $[0,M]$?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Let $f : [0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ so that for all $M>0$, $f$ is integrable on $[0,M]$.

Can I assume $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx<\infty$?

Or that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0 \iff \int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx<\infty$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: The assumptions I wrote were my work. Couldn't think of anything else or prove it.

Comment: OK, but what do you base those assumptions on? Did you try it on any function?

Comment: All the functions I could think of does convergence, But I wonder if it has to.

Comment: Really? Which functions did you try?

Comment: Any nonzero constant function, for example, is integrable on $[0,M]$ for all $M>0$, yet its integral over $[0,\infty)$ is not finite. Also, the function $f(x)=x$ is another counterexample. And also any other non-zero polynomial. And also the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions. In fact, every continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ that does not have a limit of $0$ at $\infty$ is a counterexample to your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your assumptions don’t hold. Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$. Then $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = 0$, $\int_0^M f(x) dx = \ln(1+M) < \infty$ for all $M > 0$, but $\int_0^{+\infty} f(x) dx$ diverges.